# Storing thousands of files in one directory

Tags: filesystem

I have a web-site that I'm checking for performance issues and bugs, and i came across a caching code that caches thousands of files into one single directory.

I understand that this is not good and that I/O will degrade and i also heard about potential inode problem.

And i know how to fix the caching code, but the thing is that at this point fixing would be very expensive.

**The question**: 
What is the worst case scenario if i live it like it is right now?
How will happen to the website? (right now this one single cache directory has 400K files)

I'm new to Ubuntu. And i understand that this is might be an off-topic. But i think this is a "system" question and it does not belong to the 'programming' part of the stackoverflow.

Thanks!

**UPDATE:** The file system is UFS

Comment: I have. I think i will post this on webmasters as well. Thank you :)

Comment: Important: what is the filesystem ext3? ext4? fat? :)

Comment: The files system is ufs :) Will update my post shortly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UFS works with inodes so the maximum number of files depends on the inode to space ratio that has been set. And that is a lot... a lot more than 400k.

2 problems:

- Creating new files will take more and more time.
- You will also run into other problems: `ls` will error out with `Argument list too long.` since it will expand all the files (`ls -l *` turns into `ls -l file1 file2 file3 file4 etc etc`. Same goes for `rm` and some other commands.

I know you will not like it but ... it IS best to use sub directories. Yes, can be a hell of a lot of work but you are bound to end up having to do it anyways. Better be prepared now while you have the time than after the server crashed.

Alternative:
- analyse if you can drop some files and not cache them.